# Using functions from an implicitly loaded DLL within initialization/deinitalization of global variables

Tags: c++, windows

Consider a Windows program that uses an import library *logging.lib* so that *logging.dll* will be loaded/unloaded automatically at runtime.

Also, consider one of the translation units of the main program defines a global variable of a class type as follows:

```
struct InitGuard
{
    InitGuard()
    {
        logging::initialize();
    }

    ~InitGuard()
    {
        logging::deinitialize();
    }
};

InitGuard g_initGuard;
```

Apart from the fact that the better approach would be to instantiate `InitGuard` within function `main`:

- Is it guaranteed that *logging.dll* will already be loaded when the c'tor of `InitGuard` is invoked?
- Even more importantly, is it guaranteed that *logging.dll* will not yet be unloaded before the d'tor of `InitGuard` has returned?

Comment: No language standard is going to give you a warranty.  Darwin has to sort this out, any compiler that fumbles this is not going to be popular.  So yes, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that *logging.dll* will already be loaded when the c'tor of `InitGuard` is invoked?

Yes. All references to *static* linked DLLs are resolved by the OS Loader before any of the EXE's code begins running.

> Even more importantly, is it guaranteed that *logging.dll* will not yet be unloaded before the d'tor of `InitGuard` has returned?

Yes. The OS will not release *static* linked DLLs until after the EXE's code has finished running.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also point me to any citable source for that?